# Extracting shape information from DWG (WoutWare CadLib)

Tags: c#, cad

We are trying to extract data from a DWG file (more specifically DxfModel) and cannot find how to get the actual shape. Preferably, we would like to be able to get a list of the coordinates from the Entities but that's not something I can find out how to retrieve. I have populated an array with the different DxfBlocks, and am hoping to now get entities from that list (preferably some [x, y] formatting but I cannot find how this can be done from the docs)

```cs
//Read the Dwg file into memory
DwgReader dwgReader = new(fileName);
DxfModel dxfModel = dwgReader.Read();

//Get the blocks in the file
DxfBlock[] blocks = GetBlocks(dxfModel);
var entities = blocks[0].Entities;
```

Thank you in advance,

Torben

EDIT: I am using the .NET Standard 2.0 Version of the library (https://www.woutware.com/).

Docs can be found here https://www.woutware.com/doc/NetCore2.0/index.html

Comment: this is a comercial library, and you can try get their official support directly?

Comment: I should probably do that, I figured I might as well try my luck on SO just in case someone knew because the product forums aren't very active.

Comment: try out the [samples on github](https://github.com/woutware/WW.Cad.NetStandard.Examples)

Comment: You can just loop through the entities (foreeach DxfEntity in model.entities).. then  if DxfLwPolyline for example cast entity as polyline. Now you have the vertices (x,y)